# How to separate a template class from its friend template class into different header files?

Tags: c++, class, templates, friend, organization

A file contains template class A and template class B. A is friend of B.

I want to separate them into different files. How to deal with it?

Comment: You need to be more specific.   Do you intend every instantiation `A<U>` to be a friend of every `B<T>`?    Or do you intend only that `A<T>` is a friend of `B<T>` but `A<U>` is not (for distinct `T` and `U`)?   You see, templates are not friends of anything.   Instantiations of templates are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A.h**

```
#if !defined(FILE_A_H)
#define      FILE_A_H

template<class T>
class A
{
  template<class> friend class B;

  // ...
};

#endif
```

**B.h**

```
#if !defined(FILE_B_H)
#define      FILE_B_H

template<class T> class B { /* ... */ };

#endif
```

Note that if the name of the class that is used in the friend declaration is not yet declared, it is forward declared on the spot (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend).

Further details:

- [Why can't I separate the definition of my templates class from its declaration and put it inside a .cpp file?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl)
- [Why do I get linker errors when I use template friends?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends)
- [Templates, C++FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates)

Comment: I have tried your ideas. But it failed to execute and the compiler gives the error "class B can not visit private member of class A".

Comment: @LinXuelei [Here](http://ideone.com/ouRJUC) there's a simple example (being a friend, `B` can access private members of `A`). Can you post your code and give more details?

Comment: @LinXuelei You should edit your post, adding more information, or ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks, for your on-going replies.